# Is it possible, and what would be required to modify a ventilator to support two patients concurrently?

Tags: covid-19, lungs, treatment-options, medical-device

An article from a pediatrician on NYT suggested this as a possibility, I'm keen to know if it could be done in an emergency/shortage situation.  If so:

- What would the challenges be from a mechanical/electrical standpoint?
- Are there feedback/sensor issues that one would need to sort out?
- Are the pumps in the device sufficient if the workload increases 2x?
- Would there be constraints to their use in that configuration?

  - For instance, would both patients need to be about the same size and equally sick?

For brevity let's assume licensing/legal/regulatory is a whole 'nother (probably *bigger* knowing the US health care system) problem to solve.

Comment: Did you do any prior research? https://emcrit.org/pulmcrit/split-ventilators/

Comment: @GrahamChiu, thank you for that link - was exactly what I was looking for.  When I initially googled for it I was finding mostly anecdotes or media stories of the "Local doctor rigs up ventilator to support two patients" variety.  Nothing that showed the kind of operational insights and specifics as your link did.  Thanks again.